# androidTestCompile fails to build aar

Tags: android, android-studio, testing, gradle

I have a project with multiple modules. Part of the project is broken into test modules I do not want included with the core code (as they are only used for testing). Since the latest update of Studio 2.2 and gradle 3.1, my `androidTestCompile` statements in my main app have begun failing with:

> A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:prepareXXXXTestAppLibraryUnspecifiedLibrary'.
>   File '/Users/normandl/git/XXXX/Android/TestAppLibrary/build/outputs/aar/TestAppLibrary-release.aar' specified for property 'bundle' does not exist.

Of course if I change the directive in the app build.gradle file from `androidTestCompile(":TestAppLibrary)` to `compile project(":TestAppLibrary")`  build is fine. So I have narrowed this down to the androidTestCompile directive.

I have also tried from the command line, and it fails there too, so it is not limited to Android Studio, making me suspect the upgrade to gradle. I have tried this on 2.14.1 as well. Everything was fine in gradle 2.13.1.

My back door option is to build a local aar, drop this directive so it does not build the library in the main app, only reference it. Less than ideal since it causes overhead in maintenance.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue, and I also have a large project with multiple library, app and test modules. looks like Android Studio doesn't handle this structure well...

Comment: A had to make my aar's now externally to the project, add to the libs and add directives like:

androidTestCompile(name: 'TestAppLibrary-release', ext: 'aar')